# Why category.php throw 404 in wordpress while calling paginate_links()?

Tags: categories, theme-development, pagination, paginate-links

I am trying to develop my own Wordpress theme and want to add pagination in category page by call paginate_links() function. It will generate the links [1,2,... Next] perfectly but when I click on 2 page it will throw the 404 error. For example...

Category link: localhost/abc ---> 202

2 Page link: localhost/abc/page/2 ---> 404

Where abc is the name of the category.

category.php

```
<?php
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    ?>
    <div>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p> <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue reading &raquo;</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
echo paginate_links();
?>
```

Above code works fine for index.php

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. To work pagination for a category, the category URL must be like...

```
localhost/category/abc
```

and it works fine.